Find deleted questions?
So, I have enough rep to view deleted questions. If I have a link to one, it will appear.
But I can't find any deleted questions. I have to know where they are (the link). Searching doesn't work and ignores deleted questions.
As expected, deleted questions don't appear in anyone's profile.
Is there some trick a non-moderator with enough rep can use to find deleted questions?
I can easily accept a "no soup for you" response, but thought I'd ask.

No soup for you. You cannot search any deleted posts except your own (with deleted:yes). See the very bottom of this FAQ.

Thanks :) .....to meet minimum
